# Can I set something up to make a class do something on unload

Tags: c#

If I have a class,

```
class order()
{
    int orderId {get;set;}
    double total {get;set;}
    public order(){}
    ...
}
```

Is there something I can overload so that c# does something every time it is going to be unloaded, instead of telling it I want it to be done?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order activeOrder = new Order();
            // do stuff to the order
            activeOrder = new Order(); <---- Automatically commit any changes to the order, since I am starting a new one. 
        }
```

Comment: C# has destructors, but they are not deterministic.

Comment: There may be a lot of context that I'm missing... but I would ask the question, just because you can, does that mean you should? I think anyone who knows anything about the Singleton pattern and its implications would raise an eyebrow at seeing an Order be implemented as a singleton. I'd just recommend checking out some pros/cons type thing before getting too deep into a headache. For example, is it absolutely true that, at any given point in time in the system, only one Order object can ever exist? That seems unlikely based on the nature of orders, and that is what the Singleton implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread-safety aside:

```
class Order()
{
  static Order instance;

  int orderId {get;set;}
  double total {get;set;}
  public Order()
  {
    if (instance != null)
      instance.Unload();
    instance = this;
  }
  ...
  public Unload()
  {
  }
}
```

This still leaves a question of who will unload the last instance of `Order`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking doesn't really make sense. When you assign a new `Order` instance to the `activeOrder` variable, the first `Order` instance isn't "unloaded". It just becomes eligible to garbage collection (unless it is also referenced somewhere else). This means that the next time the GC will run, the instance will be collected, and the finalizer will run if it's defined. The problem is that it's completely non-deterministic: you don't know when the GC will run.

There is no way for the `Order` class to detect that the variable is assigned a new instance. All you can do is write a finalizer, but since you don't know when it will run, it's probably not a good idea. You should commit the changes explicitly when you're done working with the current `Order`.

Comment: That's actually pretty close to what I was expecting to hear. I was unsure if there was a way to know when the GC would run, or to make sure that only one instance of Order could exist at a time.

Comment: That being said, I did find a sort-of solution, though I'm thinking it's useless.  I set the constructor to `Order(Order ExistingOrder){ if(ExistingOrder != null){ //do something}  }`

Comment: Singleton pattern is pretty much what I needed.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg, i'm not sure why you want a single instance... An Order isn't a very good candidate for a singleton.

Comment: This was less a practical question and more that I was curious and wanted to learn something.